# Using Android setPositionNotificationPeriod with AudioTrack in loop mode

Tags: android, audio

I was using audiotrack to play some sounds in a loop. Now I need to know in which period of time I'm right now, so i decided to use **setPositionNotificationPeriod** which works quite good.
The problem is that it just work for the first "loop" but stop being called after that :\

The code looks like the following:

```
...
audioTrack.setPositionNotificationPeriod(bufferSize/numCalls);
audioTrack.setPlaybackPositionUpdateListener(this); 
audioTrack.setLoopPoints(0,bufferSize,-1);
...

public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioTrack track) 
{
    Log.d("Hey I'm on call: "+numCall++);
}
```

With that I got just #numCalls# calls but I want them to be forever.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thank you very much

**EDIT: I forgot to say I'm using an static audiotrack instead of stream**

Comment: Are you testing it on device or emulator? According to documentation it should work exactly as you expect. The thing is that AudioTrack class is just a managed wrapper over the native class. So implementation can vary from device to device and there is a chance that you found new bug on your device.

Comment: I've tested it both in the emulator and on a Samsung Galaxy S, and I got the same result: just first loop notification

Comment: If I try with one marker, I got called just one time, instead of one timer per loop:
audioTrack.setNotificationMarkerPosition(bufferSize/2);

Comment: AFAIK you need to re-set Marker every time you get a notification (onMarkerReached).